# Changing hyperparameters of the autoencoder of LSTM networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have dataset features evaluated from the touch screen and built-in sensors on smartphones. I want to implement an anomaly detection code using LSTM autoencoder in python to compute EER value (Equal Error Rate) less than 10%. The training dataset has the size of the genuine user with zeros labels. However, the test dataset includes samples of both the genuine user and anomaly users. We labeled genuine user's samples with zeros and anomaly users' samples with ones.

## Data structure:

X_train from the genuine user has the shape (4814,158) which means (# of samples (raws), # of features (columns)). Y_train has the shape (4814,1), all zeros.

X_test include total (3000,158) where (1500,158) from the genuine user and (1500,158)from the other anomaly users.

Y_test (3000,1) where the first (1500,1) labels are zeros represent the genuine user and the remaining (1500,1) labels are ones represent the other anomaly users.

Normalization process I used the Standardscalre normalization method to fit and transform training data, then transform the test dataset.

```
# import libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from numpy.random import seed
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
from Keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed,
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model
from keras import regularizers
# normalize the data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train )
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train )
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

## reshape inputs for LSTM [samples, timesteps, features]

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
print("Training data shape:", X_train.shape)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
print("Test data shape:", X_test.shape)
```

Training data shape: (4814, 1, 158), Test data shape: (3000, 1, 158)

## define the autoencoder network model

```
def autoencoder_model(X):
inputs = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
L1 = LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00(inputs)
L2 = LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(L1)
L3 = RepeatVector(X.shape[1])(L2)
L4 = LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(L3)
L5 = LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(L4)
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(X.shape[2]))(L5)    
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
return model
```

## create the autoencoder model:

```
model = autoencoder_model(X_train)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model.summary()
```

## fit the model to the data:

```
nb_epochs = 50
batch_size = 128
history = model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=nb_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, 
validation_split=0.05).history
```

## calculate the loss on the test set:

```
X_pred = model.predict(X_test)
X_pred = X_pred.reshape(X_pred.shape[0], X_pred.shape[2])
X_pred = pd.DataFrame(X_pred, columns=test.columns)
X_pred.index = test.index
scored = pd.DataFrame(index=test.index)
Xtest = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[2])
scored['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(X_pred-Xtest), axis = 1)
scored['Anomaly'] = scored['scored_errors'] > scored['Threshold']
print("Output scored errors when thr =0.2:\n", scored)
```

## Input test data to the model:

[image]

## Output predicted data from the model:

[image]

## Scored_errors computed by the model:

[image]

I need the model works perfectly such that it should produce very small output scored_errors (near to zero ) for the tested samples of the genuine user (i.e., samples circled with red line) to be classified as normal samples. And the model should produce large output scored_errors (at least more than one) for the tested samples of the anomaly user (i.e., samples circled with blue line) to be classified as outliers.

But, the problem is when I put large # of neurons (e.g., 500, 500, 500, 500) for the four layers of the autoencoder model, the output scored_errors are very very small (close to zero) for all tested samples ( i.e., for both genuine and anomaly samples). In contrast, When I put small # of neurons (e.g., 10, 10, 10, 10) for the four layers of the autoencoder model, the output scored_errors are very very large (more than hundreds).

Can anyone how I can control the model such that it gives small output scored_errors for normal samples and large output scored_errors for anomaly samples to increase classification accuracy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. You said you implemented the problem as an LSTM-autoencoder but don't you want to do classification instead? This means the final layer would be dense and use sigmoid activation, i.e. `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`. This in the end would also directly yield a probability if the sample belongs to genuine or anomaly.

Comment: @Solvalou, yes I can use the Dense layer with sigmoid activation to get a probability whether the sample belongs to the targeted user or anomaly user. But, instead of calculating probability, here I used the LSTM model to predict the samples values and then compute "mae" error such that if this error is very small this means the sample belongs to the targeted user and if the "mae" is large this means the model classified the sample as an outlier.